# Browser is wrapping text at a hyphen

Tags: html, css

I have an h2 tag here:

```
<h2>INCREASE YOUR ONLINE PRESENCE WITH CUSTOMIZED E-COMMERCE</h2>
```

In firefox its ok, but in ie and chrome E-COMMERCE is split into 2 words when the html is rendered. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should probably ask on http://doctype.com/ as this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: What do you mean by _split into 2 words_?

Comment: @Valera: He means it's wrapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
<nobr>E-Commerce</nobr>
```

Or using the more modern html & css approach:

```
 <div class=nobr>E-Commerce</div>

.nobr { white-space:nowrap; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Hyphens are supposed to break. Use U+2011 NON-BREAKING HYPHEN:

```
E&#x2011;COMMERCE
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JYCS9/) — try resizing the window.

(HTML doesn’t have a named entity for it, so you have to insert it directly or use a numeric reference.)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the white-space property of CSS

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space